# Unable to get selected item from custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, baseadapter, selecteditem

I have created a custom list view using base adapter. I want to get the selected item from listview. I have tried different solutions but none of them are working. My ListView code is as shown below:

```
class SingleRow {
        String mFetchedJobTitle;
        String mFetchedCompanyName;
        String mFetchedExperience;
        String mFetchedLocation;


        SingleRow(String mFetchedJobTitle, String mFetchedCompanyName, String mFetchedExperience, String mFetchedLocation) {
            this.mFetchedJobTitle = mFetchedJobTitle;
            this.mFetchedCompanyName = mFetchedCompanyName;
            this.mFetchedExperience = mFetchedExperience;
            this.mFetchedLocation = mFetchedLocation;

        }
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        Context context;

        MyAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;

            list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
            String[] mFetchedJobTitle1 = searchJobTitle;
            String[] mFetchedCompanyName1 = searchCompanyName;
            String[] mFetchedExperience1 = searchExperience;
            String[] mFetchedLocation1 = searchLocation;

            for (int i = 0; i < mArrayLength; i++) {

                list.add(new SingleRow(mFetchedJobTitle1[i], mFetchedCompanyName1[i], mFetchedExperience1[i], mFetchedLocation1[i] ));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_row, parent, false);

            TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewJobTitle);
            TextView companyName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewCompanyName);
            TextView experience = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewExperience);
            TextView location = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);


            SingleRow temp = list.get(position);
            title.setText(temp.mFetchedJobTitle);
            companyName.setText(temp.mFetchedCompanyName);
            experience.setText(temp.mFetchedExperience);
            location.setText(temp.mFetchedLocation);


            return row;
        }
    }
```

ListView OnItemClickListener code:

```
     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



  mSelectedItem =  mListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                           String mselected = (String) adapterView.getSelectedItem();

                           Log.d("selecteditem", ""+mselected);
                           Log.d("selecteditem", ""+mSelectedItem);

                       }
                   });

                }

            }
```

I am getting the value of mSelectedItem as:

```
SearchResultsActivity$SingleRow@2399b34e
```

How to get the exact string value. Can anyone suggest me an idea. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what is the type of `mSelectedItem `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    SingleRow mSelectedItem =  mListView.getItemAtPosition(i);       
    String mFetchedJobTitle = mSelectedItem.mFetchedJobTitle;
    String mFetchedCompanyName = mSelectedItem.mFetchedCompanyName;
    String mFetchedExperience = mSelectedItem.mFetchedExperience;
    String mFetchedLocation = mSelectedItem.mFetchedLocation;
```

Answer (score 2):

got it ,in each of your list item your Getting a `SingleRow` class instance.
Do it like

```
 mListView.getItemAtPosition(i).mFetchedJobTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

adapterView.getSelectedItem() returns the reference of the object and on casting it in String it returns the string containing the class name and memory location where object is stored. In order to get the selected item you can use this method

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
```